# Ontology with non-taxonomic relations

Tags: taxonomy, ontology

good morning,

My work's goal is to build modular ontologies with non-taxonomic relations.

I have some troubles in writing them in an owl file (I can't visualize the relations between class and restrictions).

I am new at the ontology domain, so I want to take an exemple on existing ontologies, to see how non-taxonomic relations are defined.

However only those I know are MeSH and GENE and they only use taxonomic relations.
So, is there, on the web, any known ontology using non-taxonomic ones?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the most notable flat (hierarchically) ontologies is the [ConceptNet](http://csc.media.mit.edu/conceptnet). It is a common sense knowledge base, built by the community. It is one of the projects of the [Common Sense Computing Initiatives](http://csc.media.mit.edu/) at the MIT Media Lab.

The following image is a small subset of nodes and links in ConceptNet: [image: This image is taken from the ConceptNet website]

Answer (score 2):

If by non taxonomic, you mean not only subclass relations or some kind of is-a relation, did you look for [dbpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Ontology) or [music ontology](http://musicontology.com)

Or what do you mean exactly with "non-taxonomic relations"?

Comment: By non-taxonomic, i mean no hierarchy between the classes, they are all equivalent. So, i will not have Subclasses and Superclasses, and no is-a relations, to make it clearer, my ontology will be constructed of splitted sentences: for exemple " breast cancer affects women" my classes will be "breast cancer" and "women" and the relation between them will be "affects". For now the only thing I am struggling in is making restriction in this relation, and I guess that if I see an exemple of what I want to do, may be I can find my problem.

Comment: you can filter non-taxonomic relations from existing ontology.

Comment: so if i understand, you want to be able to put restriction on some relations such as "breast cancer" affects *only* women. is this correct?

Comment: Just to know, what tool are you using to define you ontology? Protégé? none? something else?
And do you have requirements on the owl profile you want to use?

Comment: I am using the Jena api, and I don't really have requirements for the owl profile: just classes, relations and restrictions.

Comment: ok, so you're looking for some kind of code snippet? if so, do you have a basis of what you are doing?

Comment: thank you, I have already find my solution. As I said, I am a begginer in ontology domain. I find the code I need and now I am able to build my ontology. Still I have to dig deeper and learn more about ontology in order to be able to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on previous answers/comments...
[SNOMED CT](http://www.ihtsdo.org/snomed-ct/) is heavy with taxonmic relationships. Specifically it uses IS-A relationships to organise the concepts. However there are a lot of other relationships.
For example relationships like

> Family history of breast cancer 1 gene mutation
>
> - Finding context : Known present
> - Associated finding :BRCA1 gene mutation positive
> - Temporal context : Current or past Subject
> - Relationship context : Person in family of subject

However, not all these defining properties are specified (either not done yet, or not possible) and the taxonomy is important, and actually determined largely by these properties through classification (as with many ontologies)

For example. Consider these statements - "Biped HAS 2 Legs"(defined) & "Person HAS 2 Legs"
The classifier will infer an IS-A relationship between the two.

Anyway, you could 'delete' the IS-A relationships, but I don't think you'll have anything of value, and I don't know why you'd want to exclude taxanomic relationships.. They're significant.

BTW, "breast cancer affects women" if your using a [closed world assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_world_assumption) this is an invalid statement. Men can also get breast cancer.

And Finally, SNOMED CT isn't 'in' OWL format - but can be transformed into such (e.g. Using Perl).

Answer (score 0):

SNOMED CT heavily uses non-taxonomic relations, and it is written in OWL so you can see exactly how everything is implemented.